# IntelliJ: Change standard commit message

Tags: intellij-idea

I am not sure if I did something stupid that my IntelliJ does this, but when I commit changes in SVN I always have the same predefined commit message in the text area ("changed imageservlet"), which is kinda annoying. (in a VERY light grey)

Does anyone know how I can get rid of that or why this occured?

[image: Screenshot of commit message]

Comment: As far as I know, it should display the last commit message, not always the same one. You manually edit `.idea/workspace.xml` and under `<component name="VcsManagerConfiguration">` remove all of the `<MESSAGE>` elements ... it might help

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Under "Version Control" and "Confirmation", you have a check button : "Clear initial commit message".

That might be a better solution in case you want to always have an empty text-field to input your commit message. Otherwise you can modify that file.

**UPDATE IntelliJ Version:**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-183.5912.21, built on February 26, 2019
macOS 10.14.3
```

Option `Clear initial commit message` is now under `Version Control` > `Commit Dialog`

[image]

Comment: Looks like "Clear initial commit message" been moved to Version Control -> Commit Dialog in the Windows version 2018.1 anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this by editing the .idea/workspace.xml in the following row:

```html
<list default="true" readonly="true" id="..." name="Default" comment="CHANGE DEFAULT MESSAGE HERE">
```

Thanks to Bohuslav Burghardt for pointing out the correct file to edit.