# Can I configure IntelliJ so it doesn't remember my last commit message?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I commit changes in IntelliJ, the commit message is prepopulated with the commit message of my last commit. I sometimes then forget to update the message, and commit with incorrect commit messages. I'd rather it was empty so I'd get an error/warning if I forgot to enter one.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217851/intellij-change-standard-commit-message) deals with fixing corrupted settings. I'm trying to disable it altogether.

Can I configure IntelliJ to not remember my last commit message?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

File > Settings > Version Control > Commit Dialog > Clear initial commit message

Comment: this is great, if any IDEA developer reads this, consider making this behaviour as default please

Comment: As expected, applies to RubyMine as well

Comment: I was struggling with this stupid (idiotic, moronic) default setting. Why the hell will anyone want this?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem as you, forgetting to update the commit message. I created [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10966-clear-vcs-message-on-commit), it basically clears message after you successfully commit something. It doesn't delete the message if you close commit window without committing. Check it out, it might work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this plugin! Clear _after_ commit is how IntelliJ should work by default. For users of this plugin, remember to set the built-in **Clear initial commit message** off. That way you can use the already entered message when committing changelists, while still having the box empty for new commits.

Answer (score 1):

For PhpStorm (Mac) it's in:

`PhpStorm > Preferences > Version Control > Commit Dialog`

*Note: I googled 'disable phpstorm default commit message', and arrived here.*